# Where can I find the users' manual for a Nikon AF Nikkor 28-80mm f:3.5-5.6 D (NOT G) lens?

Tags: lens, nikon

The tittle says it all.  I hope someone can point me to a download link.

Comment: What do you expect to learn from this manual?

Comment: I bought the lens used and it is my first AF lens.  I just want to learn how to use it properly.  --Thanks, Casey.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about *this* lens, but in general, the manual for lenses is mostly a collection of obligatory warnings in fourteen different languages. ("Don't look at the sun. Don't balance on top of a pile of unstable objects. Don't use gasoline to clean your lens.")

It might list the accessories included (front and and rear caps, a lens hood) and maybe have a diagram labeling all of the dials. But, except for a few very quirky and exceptional lenses — which yours is not — there's nothing really special here, and the lens manual is going to be one of the least useful ways to learn the relevant things.

Your *camera* manual will tell you how to attach the lens, if you don't know already, and may have some other useful information. Everything else should be straightforward. If there's something that's *not*, feel free to ask about it here as a new question.